# Javascript - Find path to object reference in nested object

Tags: javascript

How can i recursively search a nested object to find the PATH to an object reference I'm providing?

My original object looks like:

```
a = {
 b: [
  { children: [...more objects] },
  { children: [] }
  etc..
 ],
 c: [
  { children: [...more objects] },
  { children: [] }
  etc..
 ]
}
```

I would like to call a function `findDeepAndStorePath(a, obj)` which would find the object reference and store the path to it in an array of indexes such as: ['b', 0, 1, 2].

Comment: You should write Your own code with event emitter that will walk mixed data

Comment: Sorry, do you mind elaborating on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
function findPath(a, obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {                                         // for each key in the object obj
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                             // if it's an owned key
            if(a === obj[key]) return key;                        // if the item beign searched is at this key then return this key as the path
            else if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {   // otherwise if the item at this key is also an object
                var path = findPath(a, obj[key]);                 // search for the item a in that object
                if(path) return key + "." + path;                 // if found then the path is this key followed by the result of the search
            }
        }
    }
}

var obj = {
  "a": [1, 2, {"o": 5}, 7],
  "b": [0, [{"bb": [0, "str"]}]]
};

console.log(findPath(5, obj));
console.log(findPath("str", obj).split("."));                     // if you want to get the path as an array you can simply split the result of findPath
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and check the values. If found, then the actual path is returned and the iteration stops. If not, all possible pathes are checked.

This proposal respects numeric keys off arrays.

```js
function findPath(a, obj) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
            result = p.concat(Array.isArray(o) ? +k : k);
            return o[k] === a || o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && iter(o[k], result);
        });
    }
    var result;
    return iter(obj, []) && result || undefined;
}

var obj = { a: [1, 2, { o: 5 }, 7], b: [0, [{ bb: [0, "str"] }]] };

console.log(findPath(5, obj));     // ["a", 2, "o"]
console.log(findPath("str", obj)); // ["b", 1, 0, "bb", 1]
console.log(findPath(42, obj));    // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) for all our data processing needs. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd use it for your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const findPath = (id, data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'key',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);

const obj = { a: [1, 2, { o: 5 }, 7], b: [0, [{ bb: [0, 'str'] }]] };

console.log(findPath(5, obj));
// => [ 'a', 2, 'o' ]
console.log(findPath('str', obj));
// => [ 'b', 1, 0, 'bb', 1 ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)