# Get parent and grandparent keys from a value inside a deep nested object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I’ve got a deep nested JavaScript Object and I know a value which is at the object’s lowest position. I want to know the parent key and grandparent key.

I set up a jsbin
https://jsbin.com/yimugezuxe/edit?js,console

Based on the value 'uniqueID#9aserdf' I want to know/return its parent keys: 'Stage 2' and 'Level 2' from the object below:

```
const obj = {
    "Level 1": {
        "Stage 1": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 1",
            "id": "Parent1#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Steve",
                "id": "uniqueID1"
            },
            {
                "title": "James",
                "id": "uniqueID#9"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    "Level 2": {
        "Stage 1": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 4",
            "id": "Parent4#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Tim",
                "id": "uniqueIDadsf"
            },
            {
                "title": "Hans",
                "id": "uniqueID#9asdf"
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "Stage 2": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 10",
            "id": "Parent10#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Chris",
                "id": "uniqueIDadsf33"
            },
            {
                "title": "Jack",
                "id": "uniqueID#9aserdf"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};

// based on the value 'uniqueID#9aserdf' I want to know/return its parent keys: 'Stage 2' and 'Level 2'
```

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried so we can assist you.

Comment: I was trying a for..in loop but since it is nested at second level I got confused. Do I need nested for..in loop?

Comment: Finding the element is covered in [Find by key deep in a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15523514/215552)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Find path to object reference in nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636000/javascript-find-path-to-object-reference-in-nested-object)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is a different structure. Sorry. I’m really struggling to adapt that.

Comment: The answers are independent of structure. I've posted an answer which adapts the two linked answers with almost no change to the code...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The duplicate version does indeed work independently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636296/2258480 — Sorry and Thank You

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code:**

It uses recursion and will provide the parent nodes.

```js
const obj = {
    "Level 1": {
        "Stage 1": [{
            "title": "Parent 1",
            "id": "Parent1#id",
            "Children": [{
                    "title": "Steve",
                    "id": "uniqueID1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "James",
                    "id": "uniqueID#9"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    "Level 2": {
        "Stage 1": [{
            "title": "Parent 4",
            "id": "Parent4#id",
            "Children": [{
                    "title": "Tim",
                    "id": "uniqueIDadsf"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Hans",
                    "id": "uniqueID#9asdf"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "Stage 2": [{
            "title": "Parent 10",
            "id": "Parent10#id",
            "Children": [{
                    "title": "Chris",
                    "id": "uniqueIDadsf33"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Jack",
                    "id": "uniqueID#9aserdf"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
};

let path = [];


function getParentAndGrandParent(path, json, value) {

    for (var key in json) {

        if (typeof json[key] === 'object') {
            path.push(key.toString());
            // console.log("PAth : " + path)
            getParentAndGrandParent(path, json[key], value);
            path.pop();
        } else {
            if (json[key] == value) {
                console.log("Parent : " + path);
            }
        }
    }

}

getParentAndGrandParent(path, obj, 'uniqueID#9asdf')
```

Comment: That is very elegant, however, if I try an return statement it is somehow undefined:
So instead of: `console.log("Parent : " + path);` I did this: `return path;`

Comment: @Kalaschnik  can try to create a promise and resolve the value from it eg:  resolve(path)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  for (var prop2 in obj[prop]) {

  }
}
```

Then use this method to iterate down and check

Here is a full example:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  for (var prop2 in obj[prop]) {
    //console.log(prop2);
    for (var prop3 in obj[prop][prop2]) {
      //console.log("->"+prop3);
      for (var prop4 in obj[prop][prop2][prop3]) {
        //console.log("->"+"->"+prop4);
        for (var prop5 in obj[prop][prop2][prop3][prop4]) {
          //console.log("->"+"->"+"->"+prop5);
          for (var prop6 in obj[prop][prop2][prop3][prop4][prop5]) {
            //console.log("->"+"->"+"->"+"->"+prop6);
            if (obj[prop][prop2][prop3][prop4][prop5][prop6] == "uniqueID#9aserdf") {
              console.log("Stage :" +prop2 + " == Level :" + prop);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can take away the comments in the code, to help see where you are in the object.

Comment: Okay, going for a nested loop is what I thought. Yet I thought there is something more elegant to solve this (aka functional)?

Comment: can’t go further down then stage ...`for (let level in obj) {
  for (let stage in obj[level]) {
      console.log(stage)
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a function that returns a tuple with the Level and the Stage and if there is no matching ChildrenId returns [null, null].

It is a bit messy but I haven't found an easy way to do it.

```
const findAncestors = (obj, ChildrenId) => {

    let stageResult = null;

    const result = Object.entries(obj).find(level => {
        const validLevel = Object.values(level[1]).find((stage, index) => {
            const validId = stage[0].Children.some(children => {
                return children.id === ChildrenId
            })
            if (validId) {
                stageResult = Object.keys(level[1])[index];
            }
            return validId;
        })
        return validLevel != undefined;
    })

    return stageResult === null ? [null, null] : [result[0], stageResult];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified `getObject` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15524326/215552) by [Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339964/zach) to [Find by key deep in a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15523514/215552) to accept a property name and value.

I pulled `findPath` directly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636296/215552) by [ibrahim mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9867451/ibrahim-mahrir) to [Javascript - Find path to object reference in nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43636000/215552).

Combining them, you can get the object which contains the property your are looking for, then use that to get the path to that object. You can alter `findPath` to return an array of strings and pull just the first two if that's all you want.

```js
function getObject(theObject, propName, propValue) {
    var result = null;
    if(theObject instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
            result = getObject(theObject[i], propName, propValue);
            if (result) {
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var prop in theObject) {
            //console.log(prop + ': ' + theObject[prop]);
            if(prop == propName) {
                if(theObject[prop] == propValue) {
                    return theObject;
                }
            }
            if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
                result = getObject(theObject[prop], propName, propValue);
                if (result) {
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function findPath(a, obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {                                         // for each key in the object obj
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                             // if it's an owned key
            if(a === obj[key]) return key;                        // if the item beign searched is at this key then return this key as the path
            else if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {   // otherwise if the item at this key is also an object
                var path = findPath(a, obj[key]);                 // search for the item a in that object
                if(path) return key + "." + path;                 // if found then the path is this key followed by the result of the search
            }
        }
    }
}

const data = {
    "Level 1": {
        "Stage 1": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 1",
            "id": "Parent1#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Steve",
                "id": "uniqueID1"
            },
            {
                "title": "James",
                "id": "uniqueID#9"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    "Level 2": {
        "Stage 1": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 4",
            "id": "Parent4#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Tim",
                "id": "uniqueIDadsf"
            },
            {
                "title": "Hans",
                "id": "uniqueID#9asdf"
            }
            ]
        }
        ],
        "Stage 2": [
        {
            "title": "Parent 10",
            "id": "Parent10#id",
            "Children": [
            {
                "title": "Chris",
                "id": "uniqueIDadsf33"
            },
            {
                "title": "Jack",
                "id": "uniqueID#9aserdf"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
const o = getObject(data, "id", "uniqueID#9aserdf");
console.log(o);
const path = findPath(o, data);
console.log(path);
```